# Proof that vector area is a boundary integral?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed topological disk and let $f: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth embedding; let $N$ be the corresponding unit normal field on $M$.  The *vector area* is defined as

$$A := \int_M N\ dA.$$

It is well-known that $A$ can also be expressed via the boundary integral

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial M} f \times df.$$

But in all the references I've seen the author merely invokes Stokes' theorem without providing further details.  (See, for instance, Sullivan, "[Curvatures of Smooth and Discrete Surfaces](http://www.isama.org/jms/Papers/dscrv.pdf)," section 3.)

I'm not seeing it.  My question is: in ***excruciating detail***, how do you get from point A to point B?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a little lost in the notation here.  In particular, what does $f \times df$ mean?  $df$ is a 1-form, and $f$ is a map from the disk to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I'm with you -- I have never seen a formal definition of the cross product of $\mathbb{R}^3$-valued differential forms, though I'd love to see one!  However this is not my notation, but really the notation used by John Sullivan and others.  I can only assume that, for instance, $$(f \times df)(u) = f \times (df(u))$$ and $$(df \times df)(u,v) = df(u) \times df(v) - df(v) \times df(u),$$ in which case everything works out (even if the notation is a bit abusive...).  But what I mean by "excruciating detail" is that I also want a solid definition for the cross product of differential forms.

Comment: There are many ways of proving that $A=B$, depending on the desired level of sophistication. But there is no way around Stokes' or Green's formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, finally figured it out -- the confusion basically arises from slightly nonstandard notation.  First, however, let me review some important facts about differential forms (mostly following the discussion on Wikipedia).  The application of a 2-form to a pair of vectors is often written as

$$ \alpha \wedge \beta(u,v) = \alpha(u)\beta(v) - \alpha(v)\beta(u). $$

Differential forms are often introduced in the scalar setting (e.g., $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are $\mathbb{R}$-valued) and so this expression makes sense: $\alpha(u)$ and $\beta(v)$ are both real-valued, so we can simply multiply them to get another real number.

More generally, however, suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ take values in some vector space $E$.  Then there may no longer be a natural or obvious way to "multiply" vectors, and so in general the best we can do is write something like

$$ \alpha \wedge \beta(u,v) = \alpha(u) \otimes \beta(v) - \alpha(v) \otimes \beta(u), $$

where $\otimes$ denotes the outer or tensor product (which is defined for *any* vector space $E$).  Note, then, that the wedge product of two $E$-valued forms is not $E$-valued, but in fact $E \otimes E$ valued!

Logically, however, an element of $E \otimes E$ can be thought of as a pair of elements of $E$.  So if we happen to have some binary product $\cdot: E \times E \rightarrow E$, then we can adopt the convention that any $(E \otimes E)$-valued 2-form "automatically" gets mapped to the $E$-valued 2-form

$$ \alpha \wedge \beta(u,v) = \alpha(u) \cdot \beta(v) - \alpha(v) \cdot \beta(u). $$

In the case of the vector area, the most (only?) natural binary product on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by the cross product, since it takes a pair of 3-vectors to a 3-vector.  ***However*** (and here's the confusion), standard notation in this case would be

$$\alpha \wedge \beta(u,v) = \alpha(u) \times \beta(v) - \alpha(v) \times \beta(u),$$

and not

$$\alpha \times \beta(u,v) = \alpha(u) \times \beta(v) - \alpha(v) \times \beta(u).$$

(Personally I prefer to stick with the $\wedge$ notation because it is the only thing that gives the reader a clue that antisymmetrization occurs.)

So, with all that pedantic garbage out of the way, we can write a really pedantic proof of the statement from the question:

Consider the algebra bundle $E = (\mathbb{R}^3, \times)$ over a disk-like region $M \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $f$ be an $E$-valued 0-form representing a smooth immersion; let $N$ be the unit normal field on $M$ induced by $f$ (also viewed as an $E$-valued 0-form).  Finally, let $dA$ be the standard volume form on $M$.  Noting that

$$df \wedge df(u,v) = df(u) \times df(v) - df(v) \times df(u) = 2 df(u) \times df(v) = 2 N dA(u,v)$$

for all pairs of vectors $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ (since the cross product of two tangents points in the normal direction!), we have

$$ \int_M N dA = \frac{1}{2} \int_M df \wedge df = \frac{1}{2} \int_M d(f \wedge df) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\partial M} f \wedge df,$$

as desired (up to a change in notation).

Comment: I like this. Could you please explain how to extend your idea to higher (>3) dimension?